# Append and remove not working as they should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some weird reason, my append is only adding but not removing.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="insert-links"></div>
<a href="#" id="button" onclick="return false;"> 
<img src="http://a.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/blue_extended_icons_set/png/64x64/add.png" ">
</a>
```

and the jQuery is the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function() {
    var i = 0;

    $('#button').click(function() {
        if (i < 10) {
            $('.insert-links').append('<p style="display: none;" class="new-link"><input tabindex="1" placeholder="Command eg: give #user# 264"  style="width:285px\;margin-top: 12px\;" type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/> <input tabindex="1" placeholder="Price" style="width:45px\;background-color:#f4faff\;" title="Price in points of this item" type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/><a href="#" id="buttonremove" onclick="return false;"><img src="http://c.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/blue_extended_icons_set/png/128x128/remove.png" style="width: 20px;float: right;margin-top: 19px;margin-right: 19px;"></a></p>');
            $('.insert-links').find(".new-link:last").slideDown("slow");
            i++;
        }
    });

    $('#buttonremove').click(function() {
        if (i > 0) {
            $('#buttonremove').parent('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [Event Delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this:

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WTXgp/)

```
$('.insert-links').on('click', '#buttonremove', function() {
    if (i > 0) {
        $('#buttonremove').parent('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has saved me so much time! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are binding the click event to the "buttonremove" when the page is loading , in that specific moment the paragraph containing all other elements does not exists yet. What you have to do is to move the binding code inside the click of the #button.